# I cannot log in after theme change

Tags: login, themes

After changing the gtk-theme in the GNOME Tweak Tool, I was taken out of the session to the login screen and now I cannot log in. I can only log in using the guest account.

So in the grub menu I selected the recovery mode and in the resulting menu I selected root-drop to root shell prompt. Once there I did a couple of things I've found in several pages and in the forums.

1. `gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme`

   This is what I got:

   ```
   **(process:642):WARNING**: Command line 'dbus-launch –autolunch=4438d024dd45ef7fb2d3f4ab0000000f –binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
   ```

   and nothing changes.
2. `gconftool-2 --type=string -s /desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_theme Radiance`

   With this I was trying to change the gtk theme to the Radiance one. No strange message this time but it did not work either. I still cannot log in.

Any ideas please?

Comment: It doesnt look like the theme has done anything to grub though

Comment: No， it simply takes me out of my session and does not allow me to log in ubuntu again

Answer (score 1):

OK, I finally found how to solve this.
In the login screen I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then I created a new user. Login with that new user and went to `/usr/share/themes` and deleted the themes I had just installed. Then I could login again with my original user.

Hope this helps to someone.